# Como poner un boton solo en notificacion?

Tags: javascript, java, html, android

Como puedo poner un boton solo en notificacion que envie una peticion a un webview? desde la web mando desde un boton un toast y funciona con este codigo.

Pero quiero poner un boton en notificacion con el que mandar una peticion a la web un mensaje o otra cosa se puede hacer?

```
public class Servicio extends Service {
    public Servicio() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }

    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    Servicio(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Mostrar toast desde una web */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

este es el codigo html y javascript

```
 <body>


   <input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
       function showAndroidToast(toast) {
           Android.showToast(toast);
       }
   </script>

 </body>
```